# Change primary boot partition (Laptop)

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, formatting

On my laptop's hard drive I have two partitions: C: and  F: (Logical) with C: being the primary partition (currently has Windows XP on it)

In my F: partition I have Windows 7 Ultimate (RC build 7100).

I want to format my C: (Windows XP partition) but I can't do it because it has the boot manager/sector on it.

How can I format the C: partition and switch the boot sector the the F: partition without using any CD Media (XP or Win7)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to delete everything you do not need on the drive like the Windows and program files directory, along with everything else and then using Windows 7 Disk management, simply shrink the drive to it's smallest size and extend the F drive to fill the additional space.

Apart from this, the easiest way is obviously just to delete the partition, then extend F and with the Windows disk just run the startup recovery utility which will automatically recreate all the system files. Just curious, How did you install Windows 7 in the first place?

Comment: I mounted the ISO of Win7 RC when it was downloadable and used some windows tool to make a virtual drive, then ran it.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to say use *fdisk /mbr* but it seems it has been moved to the recovery console, which you may or may not have installed -- seems like you need to install it with CD-Media so not sure if it will work for you or not.

[Microsft Recovery Console](http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=314058)

*EDIT*
Found [this](http://www.neowin.net/forum/lofiversion/index.php/t378188.html) post about the recovery console that may help you out